# Segmentation Fault (segfault) when using OGR CreateField() in Python

Tags: python, osgeo

Receiving a segfault when running this very short script in Ubuntu.

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr

shpfile = 'Census_County_TIGER00_IN.shp'

def cust_field(field):
    '''cust_field(shpfile, field) creates a field definition, which, by calling cust_field(), can be used to create a field using the CreateField() function.
    cust_field() DOES NOT create a field -- it simply creates a "model" for a field, that can then be called later. It's weird, but that's GDAL/OGR, as far as I can tell.'''
    fieldDefn = ogr.FieldDefn(field, ogr.OFTInteger)
    fieldDefn.SetWidth(14)
    fieldDefn.SetPrecision(6)
    return fieldDefn

ds = ogr.Open(shpfile, 1)
lyr = ds.GetLayerByIndex(0)
field = cust_field("Test")
lyr.CreateField(field)
```

Everything runs smoothly until that last line, when iPython, normal shell Python and the IDLE command line all dump to a segmentation fault. Is this an error on my end or an issue with the underlying C that I'm not addressing properly?

Comment: File a bug against osgeo. Python programs should never ever dump core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this an error on my end or an issue
>   with the underlying C that I'm not
>   addressing properly?

It is probably both.  GDAL/OGR's bindings *do* tend to segfault occasionally, when [objects go out of scope and are garbage collected](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas). While this is a known bug, it is unlikely to be fixed any time soon.

Chances are you can find a way to work around this. I can't reproduce this segfault with another shapefile on Windows XP, and the following version of GDAL/OGR:

```
 >>> gdal.VersionInfo('') 
 'GDAL 1.6.0, released 2008/12/04'
```

You could try temporarily to refactor the `cust_field` function into the body of the script like this:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr

shpfile = 'Census_County_TIGER00_IN.shp'

ds = ogr.Open(shpfile, 1)
lyr = ds.GetLayerByIndex(0)
fieldDefn = ogr.FieldDefn("Test", ogr.OFTInteger)
fieldDefn.SetWidth(14)
fieldDefn.SetPrecision(6)

lyr.CreateField(fieldDefn)
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. I have tried to manually enter each line into iPython, and iPython segfaults at the lyr.CreateField(fieldDefn) line.

Comment: @mattdeboard Could you post a sample shapefile somewhere online?

Comment: Here is the download link to the exact shapefile I'm using. http://inmap.indiana.edu/downloads/Census_County_TIGER00_IN.zip // In addition, here is a link to the debug info when I run the script with GDB. http://paste.pocoo.org/show/295344/ // If it matters (I'm sure it doesn't) I'm running all this on Ubuntu in a virtual box.

Comment: @mattdeboard Even using your shapefile I can't replicate this crash.  You might want to check your gdal/ogr installation.

Comment: I've uninstalled/reinstalled a couple of times. I guess I'm missing something on the uninstall.

Comment: Have you tried running the sample at the bottom of the [OGR tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_apitut.html)?